# What did the guard who pushed Oliver say?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

In the episode "Keep Your Enemies Closer," the guard says a word at Oliver, then says it again.

It sounded something like '*seavoy*'. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

The [episode transcript](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=172&t=10232) indicates that the word spoken was the Russian word *zhivey* (живей).

[Google](https://translate.google.co.uk/#ru/en/%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9) suggests that the best translation is "***Come on!***" or possibly "***Look alive!***".

[image]

Comment: I think, given the context, that the examples of "Look Alive!" and "Step on it!" are more appropriate.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - I suspect it's intended to be slightly ruder ("oi, get up!")